# Offline page should not point to the blog if there isn't anything to read

Tags: discussion, offline

Currently the offline page points users to the blog for more info about the outage, but there isn't actually anything posted about the maintenance.

[Offline Page http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/7649/offlinen.jpg](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/7649/offlinen.jpg)

This is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***If it turns into an extended outage***, we will post details on the blog.

## If

---

What's bothering me is that it doesn't tell when the maintenance started. If I was a new user for all I knew the maintenance could have started 1 month ago or 1 minute ago; in the former case I won't come back, in the latter I'll come back in a few minutes.. If it says "it usually lasts an hour" but doesn't say when it started, I'm just confused.

Comment: Given your *if*, it should have started less than an hour ago, unless there's something on the blog. If there's something on the blog then something is wrong and then who cares when that started?

Comment: @Arjan: since posting on the blog is a manual action I would be surprised if every single maintenance that lasted longer than 1 hour had a related blog post. It's not something you can rely on, as it's not automatic.